# $f \circ g=g\circ f$. Prove that $f(a)=a$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$f, g: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous and $(f \circ g)(x) = (g \circ f)(x)$. How do I prove that there exists a number $a \in [0, 1]$ such that $f(a) = a$?

I don't get understand the question. How can $g\circ f$ be defined if $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$?

Suppose that $f(0.5)=9$ then $(g \circ f)(0.5)$ isn't defined, right (since $g$ is defined on $[0,1]$ and $g$ is continuous)?

I think this exercise is wrong; it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It must be the case that $\mathrm{im}\, f$ and $\mathrm{im}\, g$ are subsets of $[0,1]$.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that because of the domain issue you bring up, $f$ and $g$ are infact functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$, in which case the problem is then easy.

Comment: @Clive Newstead: Don't you mean supersets?

Comment: @user99680: Definitely not, you need each function's output to be a possible input to the other function.

Comment: Note that IF $ f (0.5) = 9$, then there is no function $ g : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathhbb{R}$ such that $ f \circ g = g \circ f$. You are supposed to deduce that if the condition held, then we must have several other constraints. It is common in a math problem that they don't tell you all of the necessary constraints in the question itself.

Comment: @Clive Newstead: Since the conditions are not clearly-stated, it may be that you can have f([0,1]) contains [0,1], and then you restrict g to $[0,1]\cap f([0,1])$, same for f.

Comment: @user99680: ...but then $f$ is restricted to $[0,1] \cap f([0,1]) \cap g([0,1])$, which is a subset of $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $f\circ g=g\circ f$ we infer that the output of each function is in the domain of the other, hence the image of both function is in $[0,1]$.

Now $f$ has both domain and range $[0,1]$ and it is continuous. Consider $h=x-f(x)$ then $h(0)\le 0$ and $h(1) \ge 0$. $h$ is continuous and hence it has a root $a$, where $h(a)=0$. Then $f(a)=a$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some additional conditions: let $f(x)=g(x)=x-c; c \neq 0$, or $f(x)=x-2, g(x)=x-3. f\circ g =g \circ f =x-5$.

Comment: Actually, $g\circ f$ is undefined here, so this is not a counterexample.

Comment: How is $g\circ f$ undefined?

Comment: Well, I guess whether it is defined or not depend on whether you allow implicit domain restriction, or do you strictly required that the range of $f$ is in the domain of $g$. If you allow domain restriction, the $f\circ g(x)=g\circ f(x)$ is true vacuously, as both have empty domain. I find it highly doubtful that the implicit domain restriction is allowed, because: (a) it's more or less something people sloppily do, and thus is not something that would appear as part of a hypothesis; and (b) it would make the problem false.

Answer (score 0):

**This doesn't seem to be true**.

Let $\mathrm{f}(x) := x+1$ and $\mathrm{g}(x):=x+2$. Clearly, $\mathrm{f}$ and $\mathrm{g}$ are both continuous; they are polynomials. The composite functions are given by
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
(\mathrm{f}\circ\mathrm{g})(x) &=& (x+2)+1 = x+3 \\ \\
 (\mathrm{g}\circ\mathrm{f})(x) &=& (x+1)+2 = x+3
\end{eqnarray*}$$
and so $\mathrm{f}\circ\mathrm{g} \equiv \mathrm{g}\circ\mathrm{f}$. (This holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and not just $0 \le x \le 1$.)

We claim that there exists $0 \le a \le 1$ for which $\mathrm{f}(a)=a$. This is impossible since
$$\mathrm{f}(a)=a \iff a+1=a \iff 1=0$$
Similarly, if we claim that there exists $0 \le b \le 1$ with $\mathrm{g}(b)=b$ then we get a contradiction.
$$\mathrm{g}(b)=b \iff b+2 = b \iff 2 = 0$$

Comment: Thanks for that example. I fear it is correct.

Comment: Careful, this is not a valid counterexample because the composites are not well-defined. Both functions' domains are stipulated to be $[0,1]$, but in your example they are not. Indeed, $f(x) > 1$ for all $x \in (0,1]$, and so $g(f(x))$ is undefined for all $x \in (0,1]$. (And $f \circ g$ is undefined everywhere for the same reason.)